# what happens in a universal implication when the premise is false

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have just started learning Mathematical logic and couldn't figure out the answer to the above question .

my question is what happens to the truth value if the premise in a universal implication is false eg: ∀x (  (Purple(x) ∧ Mushroom(x)) ⇒ Poisonous(x) )

if in the universe x is not purple or not a mushroom .what happens to the implication ?

Comment: With the parentheses as they currently are, this is not  sentence.

Comment: Hi Andre ,I really don't understand what my mistake is. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: You have $\forall x(P(x))\implies Q(x)$. Note that the occurrences of $x$ in $\forall x (P(x))$ are bound, and the occurrence in $Q(x)$ is free. So what you have is a formula that is not a sentence. Some presentations of first-order logic give truth value to formulas thaat are not sentences, by implicitly adding an outer universal quantifier. But many presentations do not assign a truth value to such formulas.

Comment: Perhaps you intended another pair of parentheses, one after the $\forall x$, and one at the end. But there are no such parentheses present.

Comment: yeah exactly .I have to have a another set of parentheses. thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. The sentence is then rue in that universe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the variable $x$ is *bound* by the quantifier, the truth value of the sentense does not depend on any choice of value for $x$. That's what the quantifier says: $\forall x(\cdots)$ is true if "$\cdots$" is true *no matter what* we bind to $x$.

For those particular choices of $x$ that are not purple mushrooms, the formula to the left of $\Rightarrow$ is *false*, and therefore the implication is automatically *true* -- see its truth table.

Effectively this means that the choices of $x$ that are *not* purple mushrooms do not contribute to the truth value of $\forall x(\cdots)$ -- formally they do contribute, of course, but in a way that makes no difference, because one more "true" in he pile doesn't change the outcome of "are they all true?".

Comment: OK got it,thanks so we have the same truth table . one more thing is there any difference/nuance I should be aware of between for all ... Implies vs implies

Comment: @Ramkumar: The truth table for $\Rightarrow$ is the same no matter whether there's a quantifier around it. However note that it is _extremely rare_ (except in artificial examples for teaching purposes) to see a $\Rightarrow$ that is _not_ under a universal quantification. The truth table for $\Rightarrow$ is designed to make sense under a quantifier, and what it does when it is _not_ under a quantifier is not important and best understood as _it does whatever makes it work correctly when there's a quantifier above it_.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is what happens to the truth value if the premise in a universal implication is false eg: $\forall x : ((Purple(x) \land Mushroom(x)) \implies Poisonous(x))$ (assuming outer brackets)
>
> If in the universe, x is not purple or not a mushroom, what happens to the implication?

Then the implication would tell you nothing. $x$ may or may not be poisonous. If $x$ was the only element of your universe, the implication would be true, however. Otherwise, it may or may not be true.

Comment: Hi Dan ,I was asking about the case where the premise is false.I.e when x is not purple or not mushroom

Comment: @Ramkumar Yes, I understood that. Your implication only tells you about things that are purple and mushrooms. It doesn't tell you anything about white mushrooms, or purple grapes, or red apples.

Comment: @Ramkumar Well, I guess, it also tells you about things that are *not* poisonous": They are are either not purple or not mushrooms, i.e. not purple mushrooms.